# Does gradient clipping in a RNN help the network learn the long term dependencies?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation

So this was asked in one of the exams and I think that gradient clipping does help in learning long term dependencies in RNN but the answer provided to us was "Gradient clipping cannot help with vanishing gradients, or improve the flow of information back deep in time."

From the explanation, the only thing that I can deduce is that only vanishing gradient pose a problem while learning long term dependencies. Is this correct?

does exploding gradient have any role in learning long term dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I would say both vanishing and exploding gradient pose a problem while learning long term dependencies, and potentially any kind of dependency in general.

1. **vanishing gradient** does it by preventing learning at all, since without gradient your optimization step won't sufficiently affect the weights of your network
2. **exploding gradient** on the other hand makes your network to learn "too much" after each forward step, potentially skipping a local minimum in your loss function and thus leading the gradient descent algorithm to diverge

Of course by clipping the magnitude of the gradient, you can thwart the exploding gradient problem. But if your gradient is already almost zero (and that's the case for vanishing gradient), clipping won't have any effect at all.

Comment: Couldn't we perform some sort of "reverse" clipping? I mean if the gradients are below some threshold to set them to a specific min and max values?

Comment: You should design your loss function to produce reasonable gradients, e.g. the [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) which treats small and large errors differently. But, apart from a simple clip, I wouldn't manually tune the gradient by myself, since an ill-defined one will likely be a symptom of something messing with the training setup.